# Can I model save to multiple tables for ETL. I have tables for staging and final tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have multiple tables that will look the same, is it possible to have a model save to multiple tables by changing the underlying table name?

```
Products
Products_Staging
Products_Archive
```

The columns will be exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way would be to add something like the following to one or all of the models:

```
after_create :create_others

private
  def create_others
    # you get the product created first
    ProductStaging.create(product.attributes)
    ProductArchive.create(product.attributes)
  end
```

Comment: Then I have to keep all tables in sync, but thanks for the possible other way of doing it.